# What is the command to remove files in Linux from a particular directory which are owned by a particular user?

Tags: linux, shell, find

Let's say we have a directory path `/home/username`. How can we delete all the files only from this path which are owned/created by the user `dev-user`? When I am trying

```sh
find . -user c70945a -exec rm /home/dev-user/* {} \;
```

but it's giving an error and it's removing files from other directories as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find /home/username -maxdepth 1 -type f -user "dev-user" -delete
```

Use the user flag to specify files owner by a specific user and use -delete to remove the files.

Set maxdepth 1 to search for files within /home/username only and not child directories.

Comment: Thank you. So this will remove the files only and not directories, right?

Comment: Yeah, specifying type f ensured that we are only concerned with files.

Comment: And how to delete files that are  older than 3 days?

Comment: Depends how you would define older -mtime +3 will delete files modified more that 3 days ago

Answer (score 1):

Use this [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) command:

```
find /home/dev-user -user 'dev-user' -type f -exec rm {} +
```

`+` at the end of `-exec` means that `{}` is expanded to the list of all matching files.